# What is the Kanji for すがり in 通りすがり?

Tags: meaning, kanji, etymology

I can't find any kanji or meaning for sugari or sugaru that matches that makes sense for the meaning of 通りすがり.

Answer (score 5):

It is 「縋{すが}る」 in kanji, but you would want to know that this kanji is ***not*** taught in Japanese schools, so almost everyone would write it in kana.  I myself did not even know it until today.

「縋**り**」 is the continuative form of 「縋**る**」 that is used as a noun (instead of a verb).  「縋る」 means ***"to rely on", "to cling to", "to hold on to"***, etc.

Thus, 「通りすがり」 would literally mean "***relying on a person in passing***" usually for obtaining some kind of information.

Answer (score 3):

The kanji that matches sugaru is 縋る, but it is unfamiliar in Japan. They often write 通りすがり in hiragana.